# Why does `left: -50%` position the child element correctly even if the parent element width is not set?

Tags: css

Thanks to [past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765402/why-is-is-top50-in-css-not-working) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502260/why-is-my-top-50-css-not-working) I understood `top: -50%` has no effect
for the innermost div in the following example because an explicit height is not set in the parent element.

What I'm curious is why `left: -50%` does work even though I did not set an explicit width.

```css
/* Positioning */

.a {
  position: relative;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.c {
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
  left: -50%;
}


/* Visuals */

.a {
  background-color: lightpink;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 10rem;
  margin: 4rem;
}

.b {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.c {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```